# Cypress scrollHeight Property is not correct when running headless browser firefox

Tags: cypress

this ist part of my cypress code:

```
let $height = $element.prop('scrollHeight');
cy.get('@otherelemenet').should('include.text', $height);
```

Tests run without errors but SOMETIMES the $height variable deviates by 1 pixel.
But ONLY when running

```
cypress run --headless --browser firefox
```

Is there a way to fix this?